# iPhone: changing CATransition causes UIActivityIndicatorView to stop animating

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview, catransition

I have implemented a non-default animation for when a new view is pushed onto the screen (see code below).  For some reason once I implemented this code it caused my UIActivityIndicatorViews to stop working.  They will been shown on the screen but not animate even when their isAnimating is true.  I figure it is because of me changing the CATransition, but can't figure out how to fix it for the UIActivityIndicatorView.

change default animation for push

```
CATransition* fade = [CATransition animation];
fade.duration = 1.0;
fade.type = kCATransitionFade;
fade.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

[self.navigationController.view.layer 
addAnimation:fade forKey:kCATransition];
```

later on in viewDidLoad I start the animation

```
[spinner startAnimating];
```

but the spinner will show and not animate.  For some reason the very first spinner I have animates but after that nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I was encountering this problem when using a CATransition inside a subclass of UINavigationController to have a custom animation when pushing or popping view controllers.

Inside a method of this UINavigationController's subclass I had this code:

```
- (void)addCustomTransition
{
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = kAnimationDuration;
    transition.timingFunction =
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}
```

However, I later found out you also have to add the same animation to the pushed/popped viewController's view's layer:

```
- (void)addCustomTransitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = kAnimationDuration;
    transition.timingFunction =
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [viewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil]; // this is what was missing
}
```

This pushed/popped view controller's view is that one that had an UIActivityIndicatorView that wasn't animating properly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I jsut realized your question is almost 2 years old. I have to add this worked in iOS 6.

Answer (score -1):

just change your time duration from 1.0 to 0.3 or less
just i am tested and it's working

Comment: thanks I have my own progress implementation that I am using as a workaround, but still want to know why the issue was caused in the first place.

Comment: yes i also try your implementation in my project and i face the same problem.

Comment: I just ended up implementing my own class to solve this, similar to your first approach, bit the edited fix doesn't seem so clean. I mean if I still wanted a duration of 1.0 why shouldn't it work?

Comment: Actually ios used single animation style at a single time. the CATransition and activity indicator both contain transition effect so first effect is applied and second one is skip.

Comment: OH amazing, that is what I thought, but wasn't sure.  Do you have a link by any chance to where Apple describes or declares this aspect of their OS?  That would perfectly answer my previous question.